# How to count outbound 302 redirect clicks on Apache Linux server?

Tags: apache, redirect

I own *domain 1* and would like to redirect to *domain 2* (no affiliation) using a `302` redirect or another temporary automatic redirect method if more suitable. Is there a way to count/track the redirects taking place using this method?

Alternatively, I can put a link on the page and instruct people to click that link at which point, I know how to track it.

The automatic redirect method is preferred.

Comment: The 302 redirect will be served by your webserver at domain 1. It has to do the recording obviously. So include the type of webserver in the question!

Comment: @MSalters sorry about that. fixed!